# What is the common name for size of the Graph based on number of vertices?

Tags: graph, graph-theory

I have gone through graph glossary at various websites, but it is not clear about the common name for total number of vertices in the graph. 
The closest is total degree of graph or |E| = total number of edges in the graph. but I want the name for size of the graph with total number of vertices. this is required for some of my variables/functions where currently I am using numVertices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term you need to search for to answer that kind of question is [graph properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_property#Integer_invariants). The one you seek is apparently, *order*.

Comment: This is the one I was looking for and missed in details. Thanks @Nuclearman for helping out.